# De Broglie relations for particle under potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The de Broglie relations connecting the wave-particle dual nature as generalised from photons to all matter particles are given by $$E=\hbar\omega$$ and $$p=\hbar k$$ *(Characterizing a single plane wave with wave parameters $\omega$ and $k$ .)*

**Are these relations true for a time dependent potential  $V(x,t)$ And if yes then is there any proof, if not then can we say that de Broglie's relations are hypotheses?**

Answer (score 0):

This relations are true for plane waves, i.e. for solutions of Schrödinger equation in absence of a potential. When a potential is present, they are generally not true (although there are some exceptions, such as Block wave solutions in periodic potentials).

Comment: Suppose $V(x)$ is such that its maximum value is less than energy eigenvalue $E$. Then what happens to the de Broglie relations?

Comment: Under some conditions one can use quasiclassical approximation and Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization rule, to reason in terms of De Broglie waves. But, as you mention yourself in the question - these relations are strictly true only for plane waves, which is not the case when one has potential. One needs a more complete theory in this case.

Comment: But we can still have plane waves when we have constant potential $V_0$